# What is the difference between gmock_main and gtest_main?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, googletest, googlemock

I've noticed that some projects refer to `gtest_main-mdd.lib` and others to `gmock_maind.lib` in my Visual Studio 2010 setup and wanted to know what the difference between the two libs is?

Comment: Refer to this link -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696376/what-is-the-difference-between-gtest-and-gmock

Comment: @Abhishek Perhaps I wasn't clear. I understand the difference between the two frameworks but what I want to know is why I would want to link to one over the other? Or more simply, is `gmock_maind.lib` a superset of `gtest_main-mdd.lib`'s functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Projects don't have to use both `gtest` and `gmock` but one might want to choose using `gtest` without `gmock` or vice versa. For either case you need a way to introduce the main function, hence you have 2 libs for introducing it.

Anyway, if you are using both then it's better to use `gmock_maind.lib` since it has an initialization for the mock framework and for the test framework as well. While `gtest_main-mdd.lib` initializes only the test part. Look at the [gmock_main.cc](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/source/browse/trunk/src/gmock_main.cc?r=391) and [gtest_main.cc](https://code.google.com/p/gtestex/source/browse/trunk/cpp/gtest/gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest_main.cc?r=21)

Comment: So does that mean that `gmock_maind.lib` assumes you're using it along-side `gtest`? If not and you do link against both how can you have two `main` functions? Is it done in the linker via weak symbols or what?

Comment: @nonsensickle, both these libs are just for the initialization. You may not use them at all, you can create your own main and add the required initialization yourself. But once you used either of the libs you have the main function from that lib. It is only one `main` function in each lib so you can't use both libs simultaneously but only one at a time. Gmock's one knows about `gtest` and calls init functions for it where Gtest's one doesn't know anything about `gmock` and hence doesn't initialize it.